# Как результат переменной поместить в класс?

Tags: php

Вот смотрите, есть у меня, к примеру, переменная, а мне нужно результат переменной поместить в класс, как это сделать?

```
$count = "image";
printf(
<div class='тут не знаю как писать'>Привет</div>
);
```

Помогите, извиняюсь за такой бинарный вопрос)))

Comment: бинарный вопос)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А можно по подробнее код изложить. Если верстаешь CMS и там попался "класс" то могу помочь, а если пишешь сам то решение на много проще.
<div class="<?php echo '$count';?>"> Хеллоу </div>

Ну как?получилось?

Comment: щас опробуем верстаю сам

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = "image";
printf(
"<div class='%s'>Привет</div>",$count
);
```

Comment: тоже гуд спс